# Blu-Ray Disc Media Player Required For Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, software-rec, blu-ray, disc

I need a Blu-Ray Disc Media Player for Windows 7.

My drive is capable of reading these discs,but I Don't have the required software.  Recommendations?

Comment: What is the make and model of the blu-ray drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically have three options. There are no codecs that can be installed, you will have to purchase 3rd party software. The three top choices from best to worst are:

1. [TotalMedia Theatre 3 Platinum](http://www.arcsoft.com/en-us/software_title.asp?ProductCode=TMT3P)
2. [PowerDVD 9](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdvd/overview_en_US.html)
3. [WinDVD 2010 Pro](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/us/en/Product/1189528458632)

Answer (score 1):

I've read about recent advancements in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) in terms of bluray support. I don't have a bluray rom so I can't test it. But probably worth keeping an eye on either way.

Answer (score 1):

According to this recent article there are now 5 packages that play BDs although TMT5 and PowerDVD 10 are still the best (and more expensive). It's one of the very few decent reviews located on the Net.

1. [Software for Blu-ray playback](http://www.reviewmaze.com/2011/01/windows-blu-ray-player-software.html)